# consulta discriminatoria sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta:

```
select tbAfiliado.id,tbAfiliado.nombre, tbPrograma.nombre_programa 
from tbAfiliado 
    inner join tbPrograma on tbAfiliado.id_programa=tbPrograma.id 
where tbAfiliado.id=15
```

la cual me retorna varias filas:

```
1-carlos-fi
2-juan-fu
3-clemente-fi
4-yesit-fi
```

Lo busco es hacer una consulta que me muestre las filas en donde la columna tbPrograma.nombre_programa tenga en la mayoría de registros el mismo dato. Que no me mostrara:

```
1-carlos-fi
2-juan-fu
3-clemente-fi
4-yesit-fi
```

sino:

```
1-carlos-fi
3-clemente-fi
4-yesit-fi
```

Comment: si hubiera mas usuarios con fu supongamos 3 fi y 3 fu, deseas que se te muestren los dos, o solo el que tenga la cantidad maxima?, por ejemplo si fi tiene 5 y fu tiene 4, que solo muestre los fi?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
AF.id,
AF.nombre,
 PROG.nombre_programa 
FROM tbAfiliado AS AF
 INNER JOIN tbPrograma AS PROG on AF.id_programa=PROG.id_programa 
 INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP (1) COUNT(id_programa) AS Total,id_programa FROM tbAfiliado GROUP BY id_programa  ORDER BY Total DESC) AS MAXIMO
 ON PROG.id_programa=MAXIMO.id_programa
WHERE AF.id=15
```

prueba eso si te sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Tal ve no se lo mas ortodoxo pero yo lo haría así debido a las limitantes de SQL SERVER

Primero declara una variable temporal donde vas a almacenar el nombre de programa que más se repite:

```
declare @nombreProgamRepite varchar(30)
```

Después una tabla temporal para almacenar el nombre y la cantidad de veces que se repite:

```
declare @table as table (cantidad int,nombre_Prog varchar(30))
```

Después vamos a hacer un count para contar las veces que se repite el dato y el resultado lo almacenamos en la tabla temporal:

```
insert into @table
select top 1 count(tbPrograma.nombre_programa) cant,tbPrograma.nombre_programa 
from tbAfiliado inner join tbPrograma on tbAfiliado.id_programa=tbPrograma.id 
where tbAfiliado.id=15 group by tbPrograma.nombre_programa
```

En este momento si haces un select a la tabla temporal tendrías un resultado como este:

```
cantidad   nombre_Prog
 3           fi
```

Solamente falta asignar el valor que más se repite a tu variable algo así:

```
set @nombreProgamRepite =(select nom from @table)
```

y ahora ya tienes el nombre del programa que más se repite solo tendría en tu select asignarla al where algo así:

```
select tbAfiliado.id,tbAfiliado.nombre, tbPrograma.nombre_programa 
from tbAfiliado inner join tbPrograma on tbAfiliado.id_programa=tbPrograma.id 
where tbAfiliado.id=15 and tbPrograma.nombre_programa=@nombreProgamRepite
```

Espero eso sea lo que buscas hacer, yo lo probé en mi local y si me trae los resultados que aparentemente buscas